# MongoDB full word search with exact phrase not returning expected results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So according to MongoDB docs,

> if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term
>   blue will not match the document

This is good for my use case, it's what I want to occur.  However given the following DB entries:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "t" : "Men's Fashion" })
> db.test.insert({ "t" : "Women's Fashion" })
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "t" : "text" })
```

A search for Men's returns the expected results:

```
> db.test.find({ "$text" : { "$search" : "\"Men's\"" } }, { "_id" : 0 })
{ "t" : "Men's Fashion" }
```

However a search for the whole phrase Men's Fashion, unexpectedly also returns Women's Fashion:

```
> db.test.find({ "$text" : { "$search" : "\"Men's Fashion\"" } }, { "_id" : 0 })
{ "t" : "Women's Fashion" }
{ "t" : "Men's Fashion" }
```

I've tried `"\"Men's\"\"Fashion\""` as well with the same results.  Is there a workaround/trick to get the full phrase to only return whole word matches?

I'm using Mongo 2.6.4.  Interestingly, it does score Women's lower than Men's.

Comment: Good question. I'm seeing the same curious behavior using Mongo 3.0.4.

Comment: because woMEN'S FASHION matches MEN'S FASHION...

Answer (score 3):

The results you see are because woMEN'S FASHION matches MEN'S FASHION in the sense that the search string **is** in the string to be searched.

The match behavior does not occur with this dataset:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ca6060fb286267994d297e"),
    "text" : "potato pancake"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ca6075fb286267994d297f"),
    "text" : "potato salad"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ca612ffb286267994d2980"),
    "text" : "potato's pancake"
}
```

with the query

```
db.getCollection('rudy_test').find({$text : {"$search" : "\"potato pancake\""}})
```

It's caused by the fact that the entry does contain the entire query, the score is just lower because it contains other text as well. You could use a [Regular Expression Query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) (i.e. `db.test.find({t : {$regex : /^Men\'s Fashion$/}})`) instead.

Comment: Jason is exactly right.  Question also posed in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20307

Comment: Yes it does contain the string, but it should be excluded from results because it's not a whole word match.  Either that, or the search for "\"Men's\"" should also return woMEN's - but it does not.  Essentially it's inconsistent behavior depending on the number of words in the phrase, and from what I understand from Dan's response in the bug report, it is indeed a bug that's planned to be fixed.

Comment: Also, regex is unfortunately not a suitable workaround since you lose the advantages of text search (stemming, scoring and speed most importantly).